# Reverse proxy via Nginx for .net core not working

Tags: nginx

I've UI built in Angular and API built in .Net core.

I am using Nginx to forward the requests sent to http://localhost:4000/api to http://localhost:5000/api

Also Nginx is serving my static files at root which is "/".

I am sure my kestrel server is giving a response back when I directly send request to http://localhost:5000/api/....

I cannot get my requests be proxied to http://localhost:5000 for api calls.

Any help much appreciated.

Here is my nginx config.

```
worker_processes auto;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    sendfile on;



    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 4000;

        server_name  localhost;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;

        gzip                    on;
        gzip_comp_level         6;
        gzip_vary               on;
        gzip_min_length         1000;
        gzip_proxied            any;
        gzip_types              text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_buffers            16 8k;
        client_max_body_size    256M;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        location /api {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000/api/;
            proxy_redirect     off; 
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;


        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to write it as follows

```
    location /api/ {
      rewrite            ^/api/(.*)                  /api/$1         break;
      proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
      proxy_redirect     off; 
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```

Comment: No, it didn't work. I tried via Postman to send a get request to http://localhost:4000/api/perform, I didn't get any response back but if I send to http://localhost:5000/api/perform - I get response back from Kestrel. Also http://locahost is giving me my UI page.

Comment: Hi Ziko, thanks for your response, it turned out to be not the issue with Nginx config but the issue was with my docker config. https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/Docker-Compose-Nginx-Reverse-Proxy-Multiple-Containers.php